# How do I sign my installer so i do not get the unverified publisher message?

Tags: windows-installer, inno-setup, code-signing, ca, verisign

I am using Innosetup to create an installer and I want to sign my application so the unverified publisher message does not pop up. The software is to be installed on an embedded machine running windows 7 that is not connected to the internet. The user will download the executable from something like dropbox into a USB and take it to the embedded computer. How can I get it to not show the unverified publisher message?

My requirements are to not use a Certificate Authority such as Verisign, Symantec, Comodo  etc.. and the embedded machine has no internet connection.

** It might me okay if the message shows up the very first time... but any subsequent install it should not appears.

I read up a lot of information on signing but I am confused on how to do this without internet connectivity and without CA.

Here is what I gathered:

The official way to get rid of the warning is to get ourselves verified  through a CA (Certificate Authority) such as Verisign, Comodo, Symantec ... 
This costs money $$ and the process is extensive. We would have to provide information about the company, licenses, financial documents, ....
Then the process takes 2 weeks. After that we sign our software using a private key and when the user downloads our software, I think the user has to be online the very first time.
Certificates have timelimits for how long they are valid and it just sounds like a painful thing to do.

Comment: You don't have a choice. You have to use a certificate authority and buy a certificate. Otherwise, you get the warning. There aren't any additional options; if there were, it would defeat the entire purpose of signing applications. *Gee, I want my malware to not trigger a warning as an unverified publisher, so I'll just fake my way around it.* doesn't make much sense.

Comment: If you are targeting a particular machine, you could create your own root certificate and get it installed on the machine in question.  Also, I think the unverified publisher message only appears if you double-click the installer, and not if you run it from the command line, if that's any help.

Comment: Luke, please post your findings as an answer, to close this question.

Comment: Use open source code signing and sign your application. :-)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl let me get to a resolution first and I'll post the appropriate answer

Comment: @GTAVLover What is "open source code signing"?

Comment: It is for the applications those are open source.

Comment: @GTAVLover Do you have any reference for that?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl No no....No any references.....It's OK. But I cannot understand what you mean by references here. with open source code signing?

Comment: I mean some documentation or any article about the "open source code signing".